# A synonym for galvanise, without the shock factor

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, word-usage

I'm editing a paper and the author is using the word galvanised in this way: "Fair trade, community-supported agriculture, and microfinance are just some examples of market systems galvanized by moral concerns and societal aspirations."

I feel like galvanised is inappropriate: market systems are not jumping to action because of moral concerns etc. What would be another word to use in its stead?

Comment: Motivated would be a milder word. But why not galvanised? Some factory in India burns down or farmers burn down rain forest to plant whatever the corporations will pay the most for.

Comment: Impelled, urged, inspired, and stimulated all come to mind.

Comment: damaged by?  (I agree with your doubts about the logic and wonder what the original writer thought "galvanized by" meant here.) Possibly just use "affected by"? or "influenced by"?

Comment: I think the original writer of the piece meant '_provoked_ by moral concerns', though whether or not that is a true understanding of how market systems actually work is another matter. 'Galvanized into action' is the meaning.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=galvanized+into+action&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgalvanized%20into%20action%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Embiggened? (sorry, but it's just such a good fit). *Which have arisen from* is a poor second.

Answer (score 1):

***Galvanise*** is a metaphor for "protect" - though extended usage may have more to do with "springing into action". But here I just think it means "protect".

It comes from the practice of coating metal objects with a protective layer applied with the use of galvanitic electrolysis, to prevent rusting.

It seems to me a perfectly apt word to use in the context you quote. But a synonym would of course be ***protect***.

Comment: It's not so much *protection* in the OP's context - I think it's more *courage*, perhaps rationalised as the courage that comes from knowing that one is protected.

Comment: Of course, galvanization does involve running an electric current through the target object.  So I suppose there is an inherent "shock factor".

Comment: Wrong type of [galvanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanism) action @WS

Comment: @PhilSweet Umm! Interesting.